# Fonts not showing up

Tags: css, fonts

I built my site on my macbook with css for dictating the styling of the page, however now i have returned to my imac the font has defaulted to Times New Roman when i view the page.

It worked in Firefox/Safari/Chrome on my macbook with the correct font used, and now no browsers display the font i used. The font itself is a default one for Apple, and is installed on my computer, so i can't figure out for the life of me why it won't display as it should.

Website is:
[Crooked Cartoon.](http://www.crookedcartoon.co.uk/)

Comment: Read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1):

Your page uses a font named [Tw Cen MT](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=148), regular and bold typeface. That’s a Microsoft font, which is shipped with some software like Microsoft Office 2007. So you cannot expect users’ system to have it. I don’t see what you mean by “The font itself is a default one for Apple”, but if you have the font, it might be installed under such a name that browsers don’t find it. This issue is, anyway, rather immaterial in comparison with the most relevant question “Do visitors in general see the text in that font?”

The conclusion is that unless you are targeting only audience that has such a font in their systems, you should try and find a commonly available font, or alternatively a free font that you can embed with `@font-face`.

Comment: The font is installed on my Imac under the same name, yet i dont have any microsoft products such as Word installed on here. It is, as far as i'm aware, a commonly available font.

Answer (score 0):

Do other sites using the same typeface look correct for you? If not, it may be that the font file on your machine has become corrupt or is identifying under a different name that needs to be specified in the CSS.

Beyond that, it may be advisable to stack other fonts behind it as alternatives; I happen to have that font on my machine, but I don't know how many others do. A webfont might be a good choice for the most consistence in appearance across the board.

Comment: TW Cen MT is a webfont as far as i'm aware, i know several sites that use it. These website show perfectly for me, aside from on my site which makes me think that maybe the coding is an issue here.